# Snowflake Regex for middle name

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wouldn't post a regex expression normally, but my expression works on https://regex101.com/ but not within Snowflake.

I have values like `lastname, firstname`, `lastname, firstname middlename`, `last-name, firstname`, `last name, firstname`

and I need to extract just first name everytime.

My current expression is:
`regexp_substr(name, '.*,(.*)( *| $)',1,1,'e')`
I was hoping this would grab everything after the first name before either a line break or end. I also tried with \W instead of \b

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
regexp_substr(name, '.*, *(\w+)', 1, 1, 'e', 1)
```

That is,

- search for zero or more chars as many as possible, then a comma, then zero or more spaces, and then capture one or more word chars into Group 1 (`.*, *(\w+)`)...
- from the first char in the string (the first `1`)...
- and get the first match (the second `1`)...
- and only return the Group 1 value (`'e', 1`).

Comment: I had something similar but it seems to fail here: lastname, firstname middlename it captures both first name and middlename

Comment: Also not sure why word characters don't work like so: `'.*,(\\w+)',1,1,'e'` why does the double backslash w not work. I also tried with single back slash. Its in their very sparse documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
.*, (\\\w+)',1,1,'e
```

Just so someone can search this, this finds everything following a comma and a space that is a word character.

Comment: You're probably going to want `'.*,\\s+(\\w+)'` This will handle multiple spaces, tabs instead of spaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_replace` to remove everything up to the first comma and an optional space. Then use `split_part` to get everything before the first space in case there is a middle name

```
with cte (names) as 

(select 'lastname, firstname' union all
 select 'lastname, firstname middlename' union all
 select 'last-name, firstname' union all
 select 'last name, firstname')
  
select split_part(regexp_replace(names,'.*, ?'),' ',1) 
from cte;
```